# Dynamic row and save to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, dynamic

I need to make a dynamic row adding and removing functions. When it ends I need to save them to my database. I've tried many things but all have failed. Cause when I add a row my function autocomplete doesn't work, then the function of my listbox won't work afterwards.

My adding line function :

```
// --------------AJOUTER LIGNE A DIMANCHE0000000000

$(function() {

    $("button#addNode").click(function() {

        var lambda = document.createElement('div');
        document.getElementById('name').appendChild(lambda)


        var rowNum = 0;
        function addRow(frm) {
            rowNum ++;
            var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> Item client[]: <input type="text" name="client1[]" size="4" value="'+frm.client1.value+'"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');" > </p>';
            jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
            frm.client1.value = '';
            frm.add_name.value = '';
            var monInput = document.getElementById('add_name');
            var monElement = document.createElement('div');
            monInput.parent.insertBefore(monElement, monInput.nextElementSibling);
        }

        function removeRow(rnum) {
            jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
        }
```

Here is my structure and input of my sunday

```
</br>
<table>
    <!-- en tete du tableau -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            Date/Jour
        </td>

        <td>
            # de Projet
        </td>

        <td>
            Client
        </td>

        <td>
            Courte description du projet
        </td>

        <td>
            Description de la tÃ¢che effectuÃ©
        </td>

        <td>
            Lieu
        </td>

        <td>
            Tache
        </td>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>

        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
    <!--------------------------------- JOURNÉE DE DIMANCHE --------------------------->
                <b>Dimanche</b> </br><?php echo $date1 ?>

            </td>
            <!-- numéro de projet du dimanche -->
            <td>

            <span id="numpro" >
             <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;">

        <input type="text" id="name" name="add_name"onkeypress="returnhandleEnter(event, this, 'task');"/>  

                        <?php
                        if($result!=false && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                            {
                                while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
                                    <p id="oldRow<?=$product['id']?>">     <input type="text" name="name<?=$product['id']?>" value="<?=$product['name']?>" />  </p>
                                <?php   endwhile;
                            }
                                ?>
                </span>         
                <!-- Bouton ajouter une rangée -->
                <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="+" /> 
                </form>
            </td>


            <!-- client du dimanche -->
            <td>
                <span id="proclient">   
                <input type="text" name="client1" size="12" class = "client1"  id ="client1" disabled />    



                </span>
            </td>
            <!-- description du projet de dimanche -->
            <td>
                <span id="prodesc">
                    <input type="text" name="desc1" size="30" id ="desc1" class "desc" disabled />
                </span>
            </td>
            <!-- ddescription de la tache du dimanche -->
            <td>
                <span id="protache">
                    <textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="taskDesc1" id ="task1" class "task"> </textarea>
                </span>
            </td>
            <!-- lieu pour dimanche -->
            <td>
                <span id="prolieu">
                    <input type="text" name="prolieu1" size="10" id ="lieu1" class "lieu">
                </span> 
            </td>   


            <!-- tache  -->     
            <td>
                <span id="tache">
                <!--    <input type="text"  name="tache" size="30" id="tache"class= "tache"  />  -->    

                <!-- début section combobox tache avec tool tip -->                 
                    <label title="Select your state"> <select title="Select your state" id="state" name="state">
                    <?php

                        $stmt->execute();
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            echo ' <option title="';
                            echo $row['tacName'];
                            echo '">';
                            echo $row['tacId'];
                            echo '</option>'."\n";
                         $task = array();

                            //echo '<option value="'.$row['tacName'].'">'.$row['tacId'].'</option>'."\n";
                        }
                    ?>
</select>
</label>
<!-- Fin section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->        

                </span>
            </td>

            <!-- calculter le temps pour le diamnche -->        
            <td>
                <span id="calculTemps">
                    <input type="number"  name="tempsd" size="30" id="temps1"class= "temps"   min= "0" max="24" value="0"  />   

                </span>
            </td>
```

Here is where I'm connection to my DATABASE

```
// Connect to the DB
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testlp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

// store in the DB 
if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) 
{  
    // first delete the records marked for deletion. Why? Because we don't want to process them in the code below
    if( !empty($_POST['delete_ids']) and is_array($_POST['delete_ids'])) 
    foreach($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id)
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM recherche WHERE id=$id";
        $link->query($sql);
    }
}

// adding new recherche
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) 
{
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
    {
        //escape special characters from inputed "name" to prevent SQL injection.

        $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."')";
        $link->query($sql);
    }
} 


// select existing recherche here
$sql="SELECT * FROM recherche ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($sql);
include("Log.php"); 



// include("dynamic-form-fields.html.php"); 


//chercher pour la colone tache
$pdo = new PDO("localhost","root","","testlp");
#Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from taches');
$stmt->execute();
```

This is almost all of my code; this part is the hardest part.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the question here?

Comment: How Do i add dynamic row and how to save them in the database. Cause mine won't work .

Comment: I recommend you to specifically state that you're using Listbox in the title, as I came here and thought you're just using jQuery only.

Comment: I'm open to jquery, javascript ,ajax. I just want to learn how want my project work haha. I'm using a lot of function for many thing.